# Word Document - Replace text in Header Table with Mergefields

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, mergefield

I have a set of documents (lots) where the header in each has a table in the header with hardcoded address entries. I need to update all these documents to replace these hard-coded address with mergefields.
The code is in an excel spreadsheet where the user selects the folder containing the documents to update. Below is an extract of where the updating is done e.g. trying to replace hardcoded value of 1 Maple Road with {MERGEFIELD Address_Line1}. Not sure where i'm going wrong but message is usually wrong number of arguments or does not work at all
Thanks

```
    Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim hf As Word.HeaderFooter
Dim lr As ListRow
Dim updated As Boolean
Dim tableCount As Integer
Dim t As Integer
Dim c As Cell

Set wd = New Word.Application
Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(Filename:="c:/......./example.docx", ReadOnly:=False)


For Each hf In doc.Sections(1).Headers()

    tableCount = hf.Range.Tables.Count
    For t = 1 To tableCount
        For Each c In hf.Range.Tables(t).Range.Cells
            If InStr(1, c.Range.Text, "1 Maple Road") > 0 Then
                c.Range.Text = ""
                c.Range.Select
                doc.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, PreserveFormatting:=True, Text:="MERGEFIELD Address_line1"
            End If
        Next c
    Next t
Next hf


doc.Close False
wd.Quit False
```

---

Or tried

```
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim hf As Word.HeaderFooter
Dim lr As ListRow
Dim updated As Boolean
Dim tableCount As Integer
Dim t As Integer
Dim c As Cell

Set wd = New Word.Application
Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(Filename:="c:/......./example.docx", ReadOnly:=False)


For Each hf In doc.Sections(1).Headers()

    tableCount = hf.Range.Tables.Count
    For t = 1 To tableCount
        For Each c In hf.Range.Tables(t).Range.Cells
            If InStr(1, c.Range.Text, "1 Maple Road") > 0 Then
                c.Range.Text = ""
                c.Range.Select
                Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, PreserveFormatting:=True
                Selection.TypeText Text:="MERGEFIELD Address_Line1"
            End If
        Next c
    Next t
Next hf


doc.Close False
wd.Quit False
```

Answer (score 0):

Instr is not reliable where tables, fields, and so on are involved. Furthermore, in your code, Selection.Range is referring to an *Excel* selection! To refer to a Word selection you'd need wd.Selection.Range. In any event there is no need to select anything. Try:

```
For Each hf In doc.Sections(1).Headers
  With hf.Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = "1 Maple Road"
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = False
      .MatchWildcards = True
      .Execute
    End With
    If .Find.Found = True Then
      .Fields.Add .Range, wdFieldEmpty, "MERGEFIELD Address_line1", False
    End If
  End With
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, with the below i can get it to replace a word, problem is though it completely overrides everything. Whats needed is to replace a particular word in a Table-Cell with the mergefield. The header section has a table on one side and in this table there a four cells. In one of these cells there are hardcoded address lines e.g. 

1 Fifth Street [Line_break] 

SomeTown [Line_break] 

SomeCity SomePostCode 

I need it to be

{ Address_Line1 }

{ Address_Line2 }

{ Address_City } { Address_Zipcode }

Not really having luck, Is it even possible? thanks

Comment: It would have helped had you said up front what it is you really want to do. Nowhere did you mention replacing anything other than a single string... And yes, it's quite possible. You might start be re-specifying your problem to say exactly what you want to do, right down to which table cell is to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies making it clearer. In the document header there is a table (on right hand side) with 3 cells. The second on has hardcoded addresses e.g.
1 Maple Road
SomeTown
SomeCity SomePostCode
I need to replace the contents of this cell with mergefields e.g.
    MERGEFIELD Address_Line1
    MERGEFIELD Address_Line2
    MERGEFIELD Address_City  MERGEFIELD Address_PostCode 
(so long as the hardcoded entries match the specified Road,Town, City and PostCode)
The is a batch job done in excel VBA that targets one folder at a time containing a number of documents to update.
The formatting also needs to be retained
Thanks